# Adobe PDF Guide encoding tables

Tags: pdf

In the Adobe PDF1.7 Guide, there's a table in section "D.2 Latin Character Set and Encodings".

Are the columns "MAC" and "WIN" the wrong way round? [For example the table, as it stands, implies "WIN" has fraction characters whereas "MAC" does not!?]

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why the columns "MAC" and "WIN" should be the wrong way round. (*Your logic to come up with such a suspicion is flawed: just because the MAC column does have empty values where WIN has entries wouldn't suggest the situation would be more comfortable. Because in this case there would a different person complaining about the same empty entries in the WIN column...*)

It's not that WIN is "complete" while MAC is "incomplete". For example WinAnsiEncoding doesn't have `dotlessi` or `breve` while MacRomanEncoding does.

No -- indeed characters like `fraction slash` or `threequarters` are not present in MacRomanEncoding. (That does not mean Macs or MacRomanEncoding-using PDFs can't display or these characters if they should occur in a PDF: these characters just need to be encoded in a font using custom encoding or one of the encodings which support them...)